# How to prevent local computer access to WebSocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I can prevent other web sites (e.g. example.com) access and use my server resources via WebSocket. I mean they cannot access the server by pointing to something like `"ws://47.80.151.189:1234"` and use its resources (bandwidth, memory) or receive data sent from it. It’s a node.js server.

However, my local computer can still receive data sent from that WebSocket url. It can still receive data even in this file location: `file:///D:/test.html`

I don't want the data exposes to anyone. So how can I prevent this and thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict browsers connecting by checking the `origin` HTTP header.

When a JavaScript script running in a browser opens a WebSocket connection to some server, it will set the `origin` header to the URL (well, host) of the original HTML that contained the JavaScript that opens the WebSocket.

Note that non-browser clients are not required to provide an `origin` header and/or can fake to anything.

You can also restrict of course based on source IP of the connecting client. Or you can require some kind of authentication.